# how to make a password input match with another input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jQuery and Javascript to create a script in which if two password type inputs don't match, it alerts, "password doesn't match." Here is my code:

```
if (!password == retypepassword) {
 document.getElementById("retypepassworderror").innerHTML = "password doesn't match";
 }
else {
$("#retypepassworderror").text("");
}
```

Note : both `password` and `retypepassword` are variables

Comment: actually it should be `password != retypepassword`

Comment: If you need to add gibberish to your question to make it long enough, there's probably something wrong with it.

Comment: thanks just a silly mistake. thanks to @igor Dymov and George sa
for telling me

Comment: You should migrate your JS password checking to Server Side checking, as every one can read your password in javascript. Js security checking is wasting of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `wrong condition` use this,

```
if (password !== retypepassword) {
```

in place of

```
if (!password == retypepassword) {
```

Full Code,

```
if (password !== retypepassword) {
    $("#retypepassworderror").text("password doesn't match");
} else {
    $("#retypepassworderror").text("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U have to just compare two strings as below code ..

```
if(password == retypepassword)
{

 $("#retypepassworderror").text("");
}

else
{
    document.getElementById("retypepassworderror").innerHTML = "password doesn't match";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You using Asp.net web application??

If yes, u can do it using, Control Validator, which is in the toolbox, under Validation.

Add Compare Validator into your WebForm,
Then in properties,  change Control To Validate and Control to Compare, assign the ID's of the text boxes to each of them.

By this,You should be done, verifying if 2 strings entered into the TextBoxes are same or not.